# Unity3d C# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity3d, исключения

Здравствуйте, решил сделать код для того чтобы можно было осматриваться и передвигаться плеером. Но у меня возникает множество ошибок с NullReference

[image: Вот ошибки]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FPSscript : MonoBehaviour {

CharacterController player;
[Space(5)]
[Header("Передвижение")]
float verticalVelocity;

[SerializeField]
[Tooltip("Максимальная высота прыжка")]
[Range(10,100)]
float maxHeight = 20f;

[SerializeField]
[Tooltip("Скорость игрока")]
float speed = 5;

[Header("Осмотр")]
[Space(5)]
[Tooltip("Сенса")]
public float lookSensetive = 5;
float yRotation;
float xRotation;
float currentYRotation;
float currentXRotation;
float yRotationV= 0.0f;
float xRotationV= 0.0f;
[Tooltip("Сглаживание")]
public float smoothDamp = 0.1f;
void Start () 
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

    player.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update () 
{
    //Movement
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    if(player.isGrounded)
    {   
        verticalVelocity = -1 * Time.deltaTime;

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            verticalVelocity  = maxHeight * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        verticalVelocity -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    Vector3 moveDelta = new Vector3(x,verticalVelocity,z);

    player.Move(moveDelta);

    //MouseLook
    yRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSensetive;
    xRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSensetive;

    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation,-90,90);

    currentXRotation = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentXRotation,xRotation,ref 
xRotationV,smoothDamp);
    currentYRotation = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentYRotation,yRotation,ref 
yRotationV,smoothDamp);

    transform.rotation = 
Quaternion.Euler(currentXRotation,currentYRotation,0);

    //Escape from locked cursor mode
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: наверно должно быть в Start player=GetComponent<CharacterController>(); точку заменить на равно

Comment: Блин, точно, спасибо, не заметил как написал место = точку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, что нет у тебя в переменной `player` ничего, а ты пытаешься из ничего достать `isGrounded` и проверять это